# List output are not getting recognize for custom library in robotframework when json library is used and list is mix with unicode character

Tags: robotframework

Here three file list.robot , code.json is input file , Library file compareLib.py
when i run this program, it always return False , i am expecting true since 30 is present in list
all file  are present in same folder

## list.robot file

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SudsLibrary
Library  JSONLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  compareLib.py

*** Test Cases ***
test json data1
        # load file in json object
        ${json_obj}=    Get file  code.json
        ${obj}=  evaluate    json.loads('''${json_obj}''')    json
        log  ${obj}
        ${value} =   Get Value From Json    ${obj}  $..code_id
        #variable ${value} return list [20,30,40] from code.json file
        log to console   ${value}
        ${compare}  set variable  30
        ${contain} =  contain_number  ${value}  ${compare}
        log to console  ${contain}
```

sample code.json file start from array '[' then three block {} then array closing block ']'

lib file

here arg1 is list [20,30,40] and arg2 is 30 , i am expecting True but it returns false

```
def contain_number(arg1,arg2):
    if arg2 in arg1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This is a question for people who have vision problems ? It's aggressive and really unclear ...

Comment: i was unable to post this question in proper format, i have followed the guideline it was not able to post this question.Could you please suggest me a way to post code in proper format

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you verified that `arg1` and `arg2` contain the values that you think they do, and are of the type you think they are?

Comment: yes i verified by changing arg1 type  to List ( mylist=list(arg1) ) then i have compare arg2 in mylist but got same result. I also simply return a arg1 in return statement and got original list.

Comment: can you attach your log.html file here

Comment: @pankaj ..could you please suggest me, how to attach file here. 
However i have uploaded iin other link http://www.filedropper.com/log_2 . Please let me know

Comment: @madhur please see the answer

Comment: @pankaj ..Thanks for answer ...i have posted one more question .I am not sure weather its related to same issue or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when you pass the ${compare} variable from robotframework to python function , it was going as unicode string

so the comaprison was some thing like this 
([30, 40, 30], u'30')

u'30' was not going to be found in the list that is ${Value}.

so i have converted the string passed from robotframework to integer in your Python file and that should work now

```
def contain_number(arg1,arg2):
    arg2=int(arg2)
    if arg2 in arg1:
        return True
    else:
        return arg1,arg2,False
```